# Синтаксическая компиляция импортируемой библиотеки

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, g++, ncurses

На строке

```
#include <ncurses.h>
```

моей программы выдаёт ошибку заголовочного файла:

```
    make -lncurses all 
Building file: ../src/Main.cpp
Invoking: Cross G++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/Main.d" -MT"src/Main.o" -o "src/Main.o" "../src/Main.cpp"
In file included from ../src/Main.cpp:4:
/usr/include/curses.h:901:28: ошибка: conflicting declaration of C function «int getmaxx(const WINDOW*)»
  901 | extern NCURSES_EXPORT(int) getmaxx (const WINDOW *);   /* generated */
      |                            ^~~~~~~
In file included from ../src/Main.cpp:3:
/usr/include/graphics.h:70:6: замечание: предыдущая декларация «int getmaxx()»
   70 | int  getmaxx(void);
      |      ^~~~~~~
In file included from ../src/Main.cpp:4:
/usr/include/curses.h:902:28: ошибка: conflicting declaration of C function «int getmaxy(const WINDOW*)»
  902 | extern NCURSES_EXPORT(int) getmaxy (const WINDOW *);   /* generated */
      |                            ^~~~~~~
In file included from ../src/Main.cpp:3:
/usr/include/graphics.h:71:6: замечание: предыдущая декларация «int getmaxy()»
   71 | int  getmaxy(void);
      |      ^~~~~~~
make: *** [src/subdir.mk:20: src/Main.o] Ошибка 1
"make -lncurses all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

11:54:08 Build Failed. 5 errors, 0 warnings. (took 950ms)
```

Хотя, если я вручную использую g++:

```
g++ program.cpp
```

Проблем с импортом не возникает.

Заранее неравнодушным спасибо)

Comment: Ой, в названии опечатался.

Comment: Может, проблем с импортом во втором случае не возникает только потому, что вы компилируете program.cpp, тогда как в первом случае — ../src/Main.cpp ?

Comment: Дело не в названии файла, program для примера написал, а лог реальный скопировал

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, что написано в сообщениях об ошибке, то у Вас подключены инклудом файлы curses.h и graphics.h, и каждый из них содержит определение функций getmaxx и getmaxy, что закономерно приводит к конфликту имен.